# Anonymous Users prompted to login for friendly url

Tags: 2013, anonymous-authentication, managed-navigation

I have a SharePoint site with anonymous access enabled for some pages. All the pages on the site use Friendly URLs. However, occasionally anonymous users will be prompted to log in when trying to access a page which should be open to  anonymous users.

If an authenticated user browses the page, anonymous users will then be able to access the page successfully.

Why are anonymous users unable to view the page until an authenticated user does so?

Comment: Do you have any custom components installed on the farm?

Comment: There are custom web parts on the site, but not on the affected pages. The pages do make use of Cross Site Publishing, but anonymous access has been set on the lists / catalogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a configuration setting in the web.config of the web application in use.

Specifically the 'compilation' element in the 'system.web' section had its 'batch' attribute set to true.

Setting this to false corrected the issue

This [technet article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2012/07/20/sharepoint-memory-leak-caused-by-incorrect-web-config-settings.aspx) explains the problem in detail.